# How to stop Flutter Firebase real time database displaying error

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, flutter

I have been finding it difficult to make the content of my form store users information into my Firebase database.
Getting error whenever I want to implement Firebase crud in my Flutter app, any time I click create, I keep getting an error.

> D/libc ( 3252): getaddrinfo called from pid =3252 D/libc ( 3252): getaddrinfo called from pid =3252 W/RepoOperation( 3252): setValue at /users/-LWybBYyVil7rVlGdFCr failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied

Some of my code:

```
final FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.instance;

final FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

final DatabaseReference database =FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('userprofile');



class MySplashScreenState extends State<MySplashScreen> {

  final  _stateController = TextEditingController();
  final _languageController = TextEditingController();
  final _sexController = TextEditingController();

  String _fname = '';
  String _lname = '';
  String _email = '';



  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    firebaseAuth.currentUser().then((curUser){
      print(curUser.email);

      _email = curUser.email;
    });
  }



       new TextField(
          controller: _languageController,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
          decoration: new InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'Official Language',
              hintText: 'English, French',
              icon: new Icon(Icons.language)),

                 onChanged: (val) {
      setState(() {
        _language = val;
      });
    },
  ),



Future postData() async {
    var users = new Userprofile(fname: _fname, lname: _lname, state: _state, language: _language, gender: _gender);

    firebaseDatabase.reference().child('users').push().set(
        users.toJson());

    _firstNameCtrlr.text = '';
    _lastNameCtrlr.text = '';
    _stateController.text= '';

    return;
  }
```

Comment: You get a permission denied. Maybe is there something wrong with your ACL rules?

Comment: How do I change that? I don't even know where it's located

Comment: In your firebase console [firestore](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/firestore/rules), [realtime db](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/quickstart)

Comment: This is what my database rule looks like at the moment. service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
  }
}